# In Go, how can I get the TypeOf a type using an anonymous field method?

Tags: go

How do I get the correct Type of the struct using the anonymous field (or superclass)?

I am trying to make this fish describe itself as a cod:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Fish struct {
}

func (self *Fish) WhatAmI() string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(self).String()
}

type Cod struct {
    Fish
}

func main() {
    c := new(Cod)
    fmt.Println("I am a", c.WhatAmI())
}
```

The output I get is:

```
I am a *main.Fish
```

What I want is:

```
I am a *main.Cod
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *are* getting the correct answer. The answer you *want* to get is wrong.

In

```
func (f *Fish) WhatAmI() string {
        return reflect.TypeOf(f).String()
}
```

`f` *is* of type `*main.Fish`, it's even *declared* to be of that type (`f *Fish`). Thus it *cannot* ever be of type `*main.Cod`.

The probable source of confusion: The method set of `Cod` inherites the method set of its embedded, anonymous field `Fish` and doesn't override it. Thus invoking `WhatAmI` on an instance of `Cod` "delegates" the call to `Fish.WhatAmI`, **but** the receiver is now the embedded field of type `*main.Fish`.

Example with overriding the inherited method:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Fish struct {
}

func (f *Fish) WhatAmI() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%T", f)
}

type Cod struct {
        Fish
}

func (c *Cod) WhatAmI() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%T", c)
}

func main() {
        c := new(Cod)
        fmt.Println("I am a", c.WhatAmI())
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/AOOltP9uug)

---

Output:

```
I am a *main.Cod
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fairly generic solution, you could separate the `WhatAmI` function from the `Fish` type and use an empty interface (see [Andrew Gerrand's "The Laws of Reflection"](http://blog.golang.org/2011/09/laws-of-reflection.html)), and just check the type on that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Fish struct {
}

type Cod struct {
    Fish
}

func WhatAmI (self interface{}) string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(self).String()
}

func main() {
    c := new(Cod)
    fmt.Println("I am a", WhatAmI(c))
}
```

Gives:

```
I am a *main.Cod
```

Comment: If the goal is to know the type from methods on `Fish`, that won't help: the receiver for those methods will be a `Fish` even if it has been embedded in another struct.